# Howto - Mass Adtext generator

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, web-applications, export-to-csv

First, be tolerent of my english^^.
Here is my problem. I work in web agency and for our clients we create Google AdWords structures with Adtexts. 
Creating Adtexts is a time consuming task!!

I would like to create a PHP application to create mass adtext easily.

An adtext is for example :

[image: Example of Adtext on Google.fr]

The idea : 
3 or 4 textareas with values (or not) on each row. Explode all the textareas in separate arrays in order to have each value something like :

```
    $adgroup = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['adgroup']);
    $adgroup1 = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['adgroup1']);
    $adgroup2 = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['adgroup2']);
    $adgroup3 = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['adgroup3']);
```

My purpose is to mix content of each row in each array.
Eg: Textarea1 line1 with Textearea2 line1 with textarea3 line 1 , ...

[image: view of the app]

Then in an other part of the page i can use the different variables :

```
 - <ADGROUP>
 - <ADGOURP1>
 - ...
 - <VAR1>
 - <VAR2>
 - ...
```

like this :

[image: Template of the adtexts]

Finally, the app will combine the values to create different adtexts variations. All of this stuff generated into a Excel csv file like this :

[image: Report generated]

Note : I work with Codeigniter, the application will a one page Application (fill the values of textareas,use|create variables in Adtext template, generate csv file.

i use the $POST to transmit data and generate report.

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: *"I would like to create a PHP application"* - great! We'll be happy to help as soon as you hit any specific problems on the way. Or did that post already include a question?

Comment: Sorry for that ^^. One question could be : how use inside the adtext template (screenshot N°2) text like <ADGROUP> to be replaced by a correct value when the report is generated.

Comment: Finally , the project will be done with html & js only for the moment.